# Apache-Spark Internal Job Scheduling

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, analytics

I came across the feature in `Spark` where it allows you to schedule different tasks within a `spark context`.

I want to implement this feature in a program where I `map` my input `RDD(from a text source)` into a key value `RDD [K,V]` subsequently make a composite key value`RDD [(K1,K2),V]` and a filtered `RDD` containing some specific values.

Further pipeline involves calling some statistical methods from `MLlib` on both the `RDDs` and a `join` operation followed by externalizing the result to disk.

I am trying to understand how will `spark'`s internal fair scheduler handle these operations. I tried reading the job scheduling documentation but got more confused with the concept of `pools`, `users` and `tasks`.

What exactly are the `pools`, are they certain `'tasks'` which can be grouped together or are they linux users pooled into a group

What are `users` in this `context`. Do they refer to `threads`? or is it  something like `SQL` context queries ?

I guess it relates to how are tasks scheduled within a `spark context`. But reading the documentation makes it seem like we are dealing with multiple applications with different clients and user groups.

Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

All the pipelined procedure you described in Paragraph 2:

```
map -> map -> map -> filter
```

will be handled in a single stage, just like a map() in MapReduce if it is familiar to you. It's because there isn't a need for repartition or shuffle your data for your make no requirements on the correlation between records, spark would just chain as much transformation as possible into a same stage before create a new one, because it would be much lightweight. More informations on stage separation could be find in its paper: [Resilient Distributed Datasets](https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/nsdi12/nsdi12-final138.pdf) Section 5.1 Job Scheduling.

When the stage get executed, it would be one task set (same tasks running in different thread), and get scheduled simultaneously in spark's perspective.

And Fair scheduler is about to schedule unrelated task sets and not suitable here.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this certainly helps. for some reason the video link isn't working. However, looking deeper into the scheduling, I am getting some idea of how pools are related to each job thread. However, I am still unable to understand how to assign pools to task. For example, within a spark context If I assign a pool to a fair scheduler? How will the DAG pipeline of that context be evaluated